# array_multisort sorts 2 identical multi-dimensional arrays differently

Tags: php

I am trying to compare 2 csv files in php by importing them into multi-dimension array and using the array_diff function to find out differences.

The methodology that I am using is

1) Fetch every record of expected csv and dump into arr1

2) Fetch every record of actual csv and dump into arr2

3) Sort array1 using array_multisort

4) Sort array2 using array_multisort

5) Compare using array_diff function each record (eg arr1[0][1] vs arr2[0][1])

My objective is compare the files using php script in least possible time. I found the above approach to be the shortest (tried initially dumping th csv contents into MySQL and using db queries to compare, but for some unknown reason, the queries are working so damn slow that its crashing my Apache server after timeout)

I have files of sizes up to 300mb in csv, though usually it would be 70k records with 20 columns and 10mb size

I am pasting the code of what I have done (w.r.t the steps described above)

```
     $header='';

    $file_handle = fopen($fileExp, "r");
    $k=0;

    while ($data=fgetcsv($file_handle,0,$_POST['dl1'])) {

        if(count($data)==1 && $data[0]=='')
            continue;
        else
        {
            $urarr1[$k]='';
            for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
            {



                if(in_array($i,$exclude_cols,true))
                    $rarr1[$k][$i]='NTBT';
                else
                    $rarr1[$k][$i]=trim($data[$i]);

            }   


            $k++;
        }




    }

    fclose($file_handle);



    echo '<br>Exp Record count: '.count($rarr1);
    $header.='<br>Exp Record count: '.count($rarr1);

    $hrow=$rarr1[0];   //fetch header row and then unset it
    unset($rarr1[0]);

    array_multisort($rarr1);   //need to sort on all 20 columns asc

    $rarr1=array_values($rarr1); //re-number the array



       //writing the sorted o/p to file...debugging purposes
    $fp = fopen($_POST['op'].'/file1.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($rarr1 as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);


     //Repeat for actual .csv

    $file_handle = fopen($fileAct, "r");
    $k=0;

    while ($data=fgetcsv($file_handle,0,$_POST['dl2'])) {

        if(count($data)==1 && $data[0]=='')
            continue;
        else
        {
            for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
            {


                if(in_array($i,$exclude_cols,true))
                    $rarr2[$k][$i]='NTBT';
                else
                    $rarr2[$k][$i]=trim($data[$i]);
            }   

            $k++;

        }

    }

    fclose($file_handle);

    unset($file_handle);


    echo '<br>Act Record count: '.count($rarr2);
    $header.='<br>Act Record count: '.count($rarr2);

    unset($rarr2[0]);

    array_multisort($rarr2);

    $rarr2=array_values($rarr2);

    $fp = fopen($_POST['op'].'/file2.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($rarr2 as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);


       ///Comparison logic

    $header.= '<br>';

    $header.= '<table>';
    $header.= '<th>RECORD_ID</th>';
    for($i=0;$i<count($hrow);$i++)
    {
        $header.= '<th>'.$hrow[$i].'_EXP</th>';
        $header.= '<th>'.$hrow[$i].'_ACT</th>';
    }

    $r=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($rarr1);$i++)
    {

        if(array_diff($rarr1[$i],$rarr2[$i]) || array_diff($rarr2[$i],$rarr1[$i]))
        {

            $r[$i]=array_unique(array_merge(array_keys(array_diff($rarr1[$i],$rarr2[$i])),array_keys(array_diff($rarr2[$i],$rarr1[$i]))));


            foreach($r[$i] as $key=>$v)
            {
                if(in_array($v,$calc_cols))
                {
                    if(abs($rarr1[$i][$v]-$rarr2[$i][$v])<0.2)
                    {
                        unset($r[$i][$key]);
                    }   
                }
                elseif(is_numeric($rarr1[$i][$v]) && is_numeric($rarr2[$i][$v]) && !in_array($v,$calc_cols) && ($rarr1[$i][$v]-$rarr2[$i][$v])==0)
                {
                    unset($r[$i][$key]);
                }   
            }



            if(empty($r[$i]))
                unset($r[$i]);

            if(isset($r[$i]))
            {
                $header.= '<tr>';

                $header.= '<td>'.$i.'</td>';

                for($j=0;$j<count($rarr1[$i]);$j++)
                {

                    if(in_array($j,$r[$i]))
                    {
                        $header.= '<td style="color:orange">'.$rarr1[$i][$j].'</td>';
                        $header.= '<td style="color:orange">'.$rarr2[$i][$j].'</td>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $header.= '<td >'.$rarr1[$i][$j].'</td>';
                        $header.= '<td >'.$rarr2[$i][$j].'</td>';
                    }
                }
                $header.= '</tr>';
            }
        }   

    }   
    $header.= '</table>';



//print_r($r);
    echo '<br>';
    // if(!isset($r))
        // $r[0]=0;

    echo 'Differences :'.count($r)  ;

    $header.= '<br>';
    $header.= 'Differences :'.count($r) ;




    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60; //dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes other wise seconds
    echo '<br><b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins'; //execution time of the script
```

Though initially i found this working on most files, but later I found that for some files for unknown reason, the array_multisort is sorting the arr1 and arr2 differently even though the contents seem the same...I am not sure this is happening because of the data type mismatch but i tried type casting too and still it sorts but identical arrays in different fashion

Can someone please suggest what might wrong in above code? In addition, considering my requirements as mentioned above, is there a more convenient way to achieve this through php?? maybe a php plugin that compares .csv files or something?

EDIT: Sample data as requested. just a snapshot, actual would have many more columnas and rows. As stated above the .csv file sizes go well beyond 10mb! File 1 and File 2

```
        236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       664|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |38972944.8                              |0                                       |0                                       |38972944.8
        236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       6653|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6655|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       664|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |63919609.97                             |0                                       |0                                       |63919609.97
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6653|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6655|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6652|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |38972944.8                              |0                                       |0                                       |38972944.8
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       6652|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |63919609.97                             |0                                       |0                                       |63919609.97
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       6654|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       6654|AAAAAA,PPPPP  



        236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       664|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |63919609.97                             |0                                       |0                                       |63919609.97
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6653|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6655|AAAAAA,PPPPP 
        236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       664|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |38972944.8                              |0                                       |0                                       |38972944.8
        236|INPQT|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       6653|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6655|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6652|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |38972944.8                              |0                                       |0                                       |38972944.8
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       6652|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |63919609.97                             |0                                       |0                                       |63919609.97
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |USD|       6654|AAAAAA,PPPPP                                                                                                                                                                                           |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0                                       |0
        225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200     |INR|       6654|AAAAAA,PPPPP
```

**UPDATE: the 2 csv files could contain different date formats as well each one of them might represent numbers in different format like 1.csv could have 12-jan-2013 and 0.01 as 1st row....2.csv would have 01/12/2013 and .01 
Hence i dont think hash would work**

Comment: Can't you just compare the `md5` hash or something? If the order of the rows can differ, what identifies the row? Can the columns differ?

Comment: The columns have a fixed order. The row orders might go up and down. Which is why I am using sorting beforehand on ALL columns. Yet there could be an instance that the row orders wont match but then those wud the error records (considering after sort on both actual and expected result, the row orders should match!) Please suggest an alternative if you have one in mind...

Comment: Have you considered trimming the column values?

Comment: I am doing that if you check the code...there is trim(col val)

Comment: In that case, could I suggest you create two pasties for the csv files? Since you've put a bounty on the question, it would help anyone trying to solve this problem for you if they had an example data set.

Comment: Could you put some sample data of the two csv files?

Comment: I would advice you start using way more `{` and `}`. They are optional to the compiler, but not to the human eye; leaving them out invariably leads to unexpected bugs when maintaining the code at a later date.

Comment: Just a thought are the files of the same encoding? that is to say is one possibly UTF8 and the other Windows-1252?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to compare two CSV files. I used an approach to check for different rows in both files. I took into account that you want to remove certain columns from the rows.

I did not use sorting, because I check if a row is in the other file and not if its at the same position. The reason is simple: If one row doesnt match and is sorted at the beginning of the file, all rows after this row will be different.

Example:

```
file1:  file2:
1|a     1|a
2|b     2|b
3|c     3|c
4|d     4|d
5|e     1|e

After sorting

file1:  file2:
1|a     1|a
2|b     1|e
3|c     2|b
4|d     3|c
5|e     4|d

Now the rows 2, 3, 4, and 5 are all marked as different, because they do not match if you check per line. But in fact only 1 row is different.
```

In the code below you will see comments as to why I did something. I also tested the code on several large CSV file (~45mb and 100.000 rows) and got the number of different rows in less then 10 seconds per check.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

//create a function to create the CSV arrays.
//If you create the code twice like you did, you are bound to make a mistake or change something in one place and not the other.
//Obviously that could lead to sorting two equal files differently.
function CsvToArray($file) 
{
  $exclude_cols = array(2); //you didnt provide it, so for testig i remove the date col because its always the same

  //load file contents into variable and trim it
  $data = trim(implode('', file($file)));

  //strip \r new line to make sure only \n is used
  $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);
  //strip all spaces from |
  $data = preg_replace('/\s\s+\|/', '|', $data);
  $data = preg_replace('/\|\s\s+/', '|', $data);
  //strip all spaces from each line
  $data = preg_replace('/\s\s+\n/', "\n", $data);
  $data = preg_replace('/\n\s\s+/', "\n", $data);

  //each line to seperate row
  $data = explode("\n", $data);

  //each col to seperate record
  //This is only needed for comparisment if you want to remove certain cols
  //if thats not needed, you can skip this part    
  foreach($data as $k=>$v)
    $data[$k] = explode('|', $v);

  //get the header. Its always the first row
  //array_shift will return the first element and remove it from the dataset
  $header = array_shift($data);

  //turn the array around, by making the row the key and count howmany times it shows
  $ar = array();
  foreach ($data as $row) {
    //remove unwanted cols
    //if you dont want to remove certain cols, skip this and the implode part and use $ar[$row]++
    foreach($exclude_cols as $c)
      $row[$c] = '';
    //implode the remaining
    $key = implode('', $row);

    //you can use str_to_lower($key) for case insensive matching
    $ar[$key]++;    
  }

  return $ar;
}

function CompareTwoCsv($file1, $file2)
{
  $start = microtime(true);

  $ar1 = CsvToArray($file1);
  $ar2 = CsvToArray($file2);

  //check for differences.
  $diff = 0;
  foreach($ar1 as $k=>$v) {
    //the second array doesnt contain the key (is row) so there is a difference
    if (!array_key_exists($k, $ar2)) {
      $diff+=$v; //all rows that are in the first array are different
      continue;
    }
    $c2 = $ar2[$k];

    if ($v == $c2) //row is in both file an equal number of times
      continue;

    $diff += max($v, $c2) - min($v, $c2); //add the number of different rows
  }

  $ar1_count = count($ar1);
  $ar2_count = count($ar2);

  //if ar2 has more records. Every row that is more, is different.
  if ($ar2_count>$ar1_count)
    $diff += $ar2_count - $ar1_count;

  $end = microtime(true);
  $difftime = $end - $start;

  //debug output
  echo "We found ".$diff." differences in the files. it took ".$difftime." seconds<hr>";
}

//test and test2 are two files with ~100.000 rows based on the data you supplied.
//They have many equal rows in the files, so the array returned from CsvToArray is small
CompareTwoCsv("test.txt", "test.txt");
//We found 0 differences in the files. it took 5.6848769187927 seconds

CompareTwoCsv("test.txt", "test2.txt");
//We found 17855 differences in the files. it took 6.6002569198608 seconds

CompareTwoCsv("test2.txt", "test.txt");
//We found 17855 differences in the files. it took 7.5223989486694 seconds


//randomly generated files with 100.000 rows. Very little duplicate data;

CompareTwoCsv("largescv1.txt", "largescv2.txt");
//We found 98250 differences in the files. it took 5.4302139282227 seconds

?>
```

results:

Comment: what if tab was the delimiter instead of '|' (pipe) where would the changes be?

Comment: the delimiter could be ',',space,tab or anything...i need something customizable

Answer (score 0):

Is it certain that the 2 files are different? I would use md5_file and compare the MD5 hashes of the two files to check if they are different in any way in the first place.

Provided that they are different, I would do something like the following:

```
$csv_1_path = 'file_1.csv';
$csv_2_path = 'file_2.csv';
$fh_csv_1 = fopen($csv_1_path, 'r');
$fh_csv_2 = fopen($csv_2_path, 'r');
$md5_1 = array();
$md5_2 = array();
while( !feof($fh_csv_1) ) {
  $md5_1[] = md5(fgets($fh_csv_1));
}

while( !feof($fh_csv_1) ) {
  $md5_2[] = md5(fgets($fh_csv_2));
}

$common_records = array_intersect($md5_1, $md5_2);

$records_diff_count = 0;
foreach($md5_1 as $row_index => $md5_rec_1) {
  if ( !in_array($md5_rec_1, $common_records) ) {
    print "Record in file $csv_1_path, row $row_index has no match.\n";
    $records_diff_count++;
  }
}

foreach($md5_2 as $row_index => $md5_rec_2) {
  if ( !in_array($md5_rec_2, $common_records) ) {
    print "Record in file $csv_2_path, row $row_index has no match.\n";
    $records_diff_count++;
  }
}
```

After you find the row indexes of each file you can do a more in-depth analysis of the differences between the files.

Comment: yes, the two files could very well be different. It could have some fields of a record not matching or it could even have additional/less rows between actual and expected. Anything could be possible. thats the reason I had used sort on both files before comparing. Can your above code work without sort?

Comment: No I don't believe sorting is required. You need to isolate records that are unique for each file and then do whatever individual tests. I am guessing this will be much faster, after eliminating a number of common records. A problem would arise if 2 rows can be considered equal in a "fuzzy" way, that means for example having rules like "if column_1 is missing from record_2 it's OK" or "if column_3 has values that are within the range X it's accepted" .

Comment: yes, i was planning to include the above fuzzy scenario as sometimes i might need to skip certain differences...any suggestions for workaround?

Comment: It depends... can you give an example?

Comment: say in both files there are certain columns with numerical fields like 36.5 vs 36.7. In such case, i would like to ignore the difference of 0.2. there might be such column. I decide the tolerable difference to be ignored... also in your above stated method, would it be able to precisely show the column which is different between actual and expected? i dont think so, from the look of it, it just highlights the line which is not matching in the other file.

Comment: If you tolerate a difference between the 2 records, you'll need to examine each record separately. However, if the field values are constrained you can simply adjust that value to the lower and then calculate the hash.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Observation**

- You don't need to sort to get difference
- am not sure how you are able to load `300MB` into your `PHP application` effectively but its obvious you don't have memory issues because i would have advised you to use `SQL` or `Map-Reduce` instead.
- Your `CSV` is a bit funny and difficult to conclude that `|` or `space` is the delimiter.

  - Since you have `20 columns` wow ... using the hash for diff would be better than the whole 20 columns .. then you can you the position to retrieve back the content

**Simple version of your code**

```
$csvA = "a.log";
$csvB = "b.log";

echo PHP_EOL;

$hashA = readCSVFile($csvA);
$hashB = readCSVFile($csvB);

// Lines in A not in B
$hash = array_diff($hashA, $hashB);
if (($fp = fopen($csvA, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    foreach ( $hash as $p => $v ) {
        fseek($fp, $p);
        echo implode("|",array_map("trim", fgetcsv($fp, 2024, "|"))), PHP_EOL;
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**Output**

```
236|INPQR|31-AUG-12|200|INR|6653|AAAAAA,PPPPP|0|0|0|0|0
225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200|USD|6655|AAAAAA,PPPPP|0|0|0|0|0
225|INPZQ|31-AUG-12|200|INR|6654|AAAAAA,PPPPP|0|0|0|0|0
```

**Function Used**

```
function readCSVFile($file, $size = 2024, $delimiter = "|") {
    $hash = array();
    if (($fp = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $t = ftell($fp);
        while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fp, $size, $delimiter)) !== FALSE ) {
            $hash[$t] = sha1(implode(array_map("trim", $data)));
            $t = ftell($fp);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

Comment: '|' is the delimiter. I know each field here is filled with lots of spaces but cant help, thats the way I receive the files...but i do need to trim each field. Also, I would love to know your SQL or Map-reduce approach. I tried once in SQL but it failed miserably because of lack of indexes and join...

Comment: Let me understand you correctly first .. is this the output you where expecting ?

Comment: Look at your `CSV` format again .... you would see that some fields just have `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can correctly sort the data by using the lines below.

```
<?php
function readCSV($fileName, $delimiter, $exclude_cols = array()) {
    $data = array();
    $fh = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, $delimiter)) {
        if (count($line) == 1 && $line[0] == '') {
            continue;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($line); $i++) {
            $line[$i] = in_array($i, $exclude_cols, true) ? 'NTBT' : trim($line[$i]);
        }
        $data[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($fh);
    return $data;
}

function sort2dArray($data) {
    $tmp = array();
    $lineCount = count($data);
    foreach ($data as $lineNum => $lineData) {
        foreach ($lineData as $column => $value) {
            $tmp[$column][$lineNum] = $value;
        }
    }

    $multiSortArgs = array();
    foreach ($tmp as $column => &$columnData) {
        array_push($multiSortArgs, &$columnData, SORT_ASC);
    }
    $multiSortArgs[] = &$data;
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $multiSortArgs);
    return $data;
}

// ========= Reading and sorting
// The expected data
$data_Exp = readCSV($fileExp, $_POST['dl1']);
$rarr1 = sort2dArray($data_Exp);

// The actual data
$data_Act = readCSV($fileAct, $_POST['dl2']);
$rarr2 = sort2dArray($data_Act);
```

However, it will not solve your problem, *unless* you expect files to either contain a full set of identical lines, that could be shuffled around.

If your use-case includes the possibility of lines missing or being completely different, sorting is only half of your solution.

Comment: exactly, I have the possibility of the lines going missing in either actual or expected and I would want to highlight such instances as the o/p. The intention here is to compare actual vs expected and highlight differences!

Comment: the usage of the above code throws me an error - "Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated"

Comment: I observed that if i use 2 different delimiters for file1 and file2, its not able to sort properly

Comment: Its doing a sorting mistake when it encounters data of 3.10E+06 vs 31E5 between 2 files. It sorts them differently though they mean the same